# Map values in excel

Tags: excel

I'm not very used to Excel. I have a column named Assets and a column named Threaten (which has a combobox). I want to map which assets has each threaten and this to be completed in a dinamic way (I mean, to be runned each time I complete a cell). I tried to use an advanced filter, but it isn't dinamic (it can be made just once).

Example of what I'm expecting to make:

[image: example]

Comment: What Excel are you using?

Comment: Excel 2013 @ScottCraner

Comment: Then you will need vba to get the output you want.  If you had Office 365 Excel then it could be done with a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to summarize your data. You can do this easily by using pivot tables. Just click on Insert -> Pivot Table and then select both the Assets and Threaten columns. Move these columns to the "Row Labels" group and you will have a table like below (Please see the attached image).[image]

If you add new cell to the data, just refresh your pivot table by the key combination "Alt + F5" and it will match the new data in your spreadsheet.